# Drop down list button disabled to user

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

The dropdown list is disabled to users and only enabled for Admins that works fine but when i edit the page and resubmit the same then it leaves a particular column blank in the `DB`.
[image: click here for screen short]

```
<select class="form-control"  name="currency[]" <?php if($_SESSION['info'] == staff){ echo 'disabled="true"'; } ?>>
                                <option value="INR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'Rs') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Indian Rupee</option>
                                <option value="USD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'USD') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>US Dollar</option>
                                <option value="CNY"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'cny') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Chinese Yuan</option>
                                <option value="HKD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'hkd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Hongkong Dollar</option>
                                <option value="TWD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'twd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>New Taiwan Dollar</option>
                                <option value="AUD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'aud') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Australian Dollar</option>
                                <option value="SGD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'sgd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Singapore Dollar</option>
                                <option value="CHF"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'chf') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Swiss Franc</option>
                                <option value="EUR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'eur') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Euro</option>
                                <option value="GBP"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'gbp') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>British Pound Sterling</option>
                                <option value="MYR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'myr') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Malaysian Ringgit</option>
                                <option value="NZD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'nzd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>New Zealand Dollar</option>
```

Comment: insertion code?..

Comment: please read that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also give us more code, you're not giving us the right code to fix the problem.

Comment: @ Alex Karshin Insertion is working fine if I m not adding this line           <?php if($_SESSION['info'] == staff){ echo 'disabled="true"'; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="INR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'Rs') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Indian Rupee</option>
```

the value INR and Rs is not matching.

Comment: @ Wils .. Rs is not an issue for this.

Comment: Use Inspector and copy the elements here.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select class="form-control"  name="currency[]" <?php if($_SESSION['info'] == staff){ echo 'disabled="true"'; } ?>>
    <option value="INR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'INR') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Indian Rupee</option>
    <option value="USD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'USD') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>US Dollar</option>
    <option value="CNY"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'cny') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Chinese Yuan</option>
    <option value="HKD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'hkd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Hongkong Dollar</option>
    <option value="TWD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'twd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>New Taiwan Dollar</option>
    <option value="AUD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'aud') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Australian Dollar</option>
    <option value="SGD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'sgd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Singapore Dollar</option>
    <option value="CHF"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'chf') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Swiss Franc</option>
    <option value="EUR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'eur') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Euro</option>
    <option value="GBP"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'gbp') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>British Pound Sterling</option>
    <option value="MYR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'myr') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Malaysian Ringgit</option>
    <option value="NZD"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'nzd') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>New Zealand Dollar</option>
```

Comment: @Brain .. Thank for your time but i can not see any difference .. its same as your own code. no changes is there.

Comment: i had changed a line of code - 

<option value="INR"<?php if ($row[currency] == 'Rs') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Indian Rupee</option>